# numpy round doesn't produce the required answer

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.5

I have the following:

```
variable1
34.30338950876217

import numpy as np
np.round(variable1, decimals=2)
34.29999999999995
```

Why am I not getting the desired answer of 34.30?

Comment: "Is floating point arithmetic broken?". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken etc.

Comment: strang.e. i just ran the code and i got 34.30